# Identify if a column is Virtual in Snowflake without SHOW COLUMNS

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Currently we're identifying if a column is virtual in Snowflake by running a `SHOW COLUMN` query and checking the `KIND` field for `VIRTUAL_COLUMN`. Unfortunately, there's a 10k limit on entries returned from `SHOW` queries in Snowflake and we'd like to be able to run this query at the schema level on schemas ~25k tables.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68686277/identify-if-a-column-is-virtual-in-snowflake) there's no way to identify virtual columns in the `information_schema.columns` view and we'd like to avoid having to run a `SHOW COLUMNS` query at the table level or having to run a `desc table` on every table.

Is there some other way we can identify virtual columns at scale?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, not aware of any native capability.  I would consider writing a script using the get_ddl() function and run it against all objects in a schema.